# Eclipse code formatter: do not wrap lines on method call

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

I'm trying the Eclipse Auto Formatter, but I cannot find a proper options to format according to my liking.

When I have a line like this:

```
MyLongNameClass myLongNameObject = otherObject.callAVeryLongMethodWithParameters(param1, param2, param3)
```

Eclipse auto formatter wraps it this way:

```
MyLongNameClass myLongNameObject = otherObject
    .callAVeryLongMethodWithParameters(param1, param2, param3)
```

I'd rather like to have this result:

```
MyLongNameClass myLongNameObject = 
    otherObject.callAVeryLongMethodWithParameters(
        param1, param2, param3)
```

Keeping the object and the method accessor on the same line, and avoiding starting a new line with '.'. Is this possible? Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can really do what you wanted, but this might get you close:

In eclipse Mars:

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`

Create your own profile based on one of the built-ins using the `New...` button.  By default this will take you into the editing window.  If you already have a formatter set up that you want to change, select it and use the `Edit...` button.

In the profile editing window do the following:

- Select the Line Wrapping tab
- In the left scroll-box, go to `Function Calls -> Qualified invocations`.
- In the `Settings for qualified invocations` area select `Do not wrap`.
- In the left scroll-box, go to `Function Calls -> Arguments`
- Select `Wrap first element, others where necessary` in the argument settings then select `Indent by one`.

You can test these settings by adjusting the line width in the preview window.

I know this is a late submission, but I hope it helps someone else who searches for this same feature.

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code style -> Formatter`

You can create your own profile with customised formatting, you can also modify existing formatter.

```
Edit -> Line Wrapping
```

Explore line wrapping and change it accordingly.

Comment: Ican't find any option for this. Where should i look inside "Line Wrapping?

Comment: This is not complete answer, where Should have to go after Line Wrapping? There are lot of options